# Microsoft Access: automatically fill in one field based on another field

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Access 2013 desktop database. It has two tables: Majors and Departments:

`Departments`

`Department code     Department name
ENG                  Engineering`

`Majors`

`Major code         Major name         Department code       Department name
 CIVIL              Civil engineering  ENG                   ???????????????`

I already have a relationship between `[Departments]![Department code]` and `[Majors]![Department code]` so that I can pick `ENG` from a drop down list in the Majors table. What I am trying to find out now is, how to automatically make `Department name` get filled in with `Engineering`.

Thanx

Comment: Why do you need to fill in the `Department name` column? You have your tables normalized ideally and you can always query on `Department code` to get department name. In essence, you are adding redundancy, extra bytes in storage space. Save resources with normalization!

Comment: As Parfait states your tables are normalized (good) if you remove Department_name from Majors. If you need to have the Department_name info in Majors you can create a VIEW that joins the two tables.